# Add inertia to react-map-gl map

Tags: reactjs, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js, deck.gl, react-map-gl

I'm using `Deck.gl` to render a Mapbox map. I'm hoping to add inertia when panning with the cursor. However, adding `inertia={100}`, or any number, doesn't add inertia. I'm following [this](https://deck.gl/docs/api-reference/core/controller) guide from Deck.gl.

Here is my simplified code:

```
<DeckGL
        ContextProvider={MapContext.Provider}
        controller={true}
        effects={effects}
        getTooltip={getTooltip}
        initialViewState={INITIAL_VIEW_STATE_AREA}
        layers={layers}
        onWebGLInitialized={onInitialized}
      >
        <StaticMap
          inertia={100}
          reuseMaps
          ref={mapRef}
          mapStyle={MAP_STYLE}
          preventStyleDiffing={true}
          mapboxApiAccessToken={process.env.REACT_APP_MAPBOX_TOKEN}

        />
</DeckGL>
```

I'm not getting any errors, making the cause tricky to debug.

Comment: I think you might need interactive map component. Not static map: https://visgl.github.io/react-map-gl/docs/api-reference/interactive-map

Comment: @maxwell good point. Tried it out and not working, though. Perhaps it's something wrong with my implementation...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things:

1- Which deck.gl version are you using? `inertia` was added in `8.4.0-beta.1`

2- `inertia` is `false` by default, try adding:

`controller={{ inertia: true }}`

or

`controller={{ inertia: Number }}`

Comment: You're right, the solution was adding controller={{ inertia: Number }}. Thank you!